# Control Camera Device From C#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, camera

I am now facing one problem which to get the live image from Camera (eg. Sony, Canon) into winform and also control the camera capture button from a button in the form.

have Anyone build something like this, or are there any similar project like this which is done in C#?

Comment: What kind of cameras? Still image cameras, IP-cameras, webcams?

Comment: normal Digital Camera which will connect to computer via usb.

Answer (score 2):

This hardly depends on the capabilities of the camera and its driver. Your biggest chance might be the Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) framework.

Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx) article or the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms630368%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Its may 2002 15 years old , interesting no further advanced APIs from microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Emgu cv is a project that provides all the bindings for OpenCV. I've used it on both Windows and Linux platforms (Mono) with great success.

http://emgu.com/
http://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code

Answer (score -1):

You can also take a look on Intel [OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).
It's C++, but you can use use PInvoke to use it from c#

Answer (score -1):

This project supports even high-end PTZ camera. [Code Project - Versatile WebCam C# library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/webcam_c_sharp/source-csharpWebCam-master-noexe.zip).

It uses Touchless.Vision and WebCamLib