# Capture image from laptop camera

Tags: c#, camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Control Camera Device From C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425992/control-camera-device-from-c)

I have a laptop that has a built in camera in the lid.

I want to write a C# application to capture the image, and save it to the hard drive.

Does anyone have a quick code snippet to accomplish this?

I am running under windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: You should show at least *some* research effort in your question, or it will be closed. We will not write your code for you.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833724/c-directshow-net-simple-webcam-access

Comment: Fredick....  i did a LOT of research....  the examples that I located all work under XP....  there seems to be an issue with the 64bit and win7....  that is why i am asking.

Comment: That information should've gone into the question, perhaps it wouldn't have been closed.

Comment: lots of SO stormtroopers...  quick to close a question without allowing people to respond.

Answer (score 5):

The Emgu cv library is overkill for this, but here is an example in 7 lines:

```
ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

(source: http://emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Capture_in_7_lines_of_code)

Comment: In my case in MS WIndows 10 I see only black screen instead of video stream via this framework but for instance? Skype video settings showing video  well. So This platform is not good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let me point you towards the DirectShow library.

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html

Find an appropriate sample that runs, then inspect the source code.

---

Here's another link that you may find helpful:
[C# + DirectShow.NET = Simple WebCam access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833724/c-directshow-net-simple-webcam-access)